# How do I show that I'm getting the smallest number of conflicts with Git by using K&R instead of B&D as the coding standard?

Tags: c#, git, coding-style, merge-conflict-resolution

Git is smart and will "follow" changes in history to make merging easier and auto merge more for me. Conflicts are delineated by the lines that have not changed around the change. With K&R you get no ambiguous lines that have only "{" in them like you would in B&D. How would I test the limit of the context sensitivity that Git has in terms of the lines that surround a change?

I want to avoid resolving conflicts that I may not need to. But I need some way to test how many potential conflicts I will save by switching to K&R and the additional context it brings.

So far, Git is too smart to get fooled by trivial examples.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll be resorting to looking at the source code for git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the closest thing I have found so far as evidence to this.
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bram-Cohen-speaks-up-about-patience-diff-td2277041.html

The e-mail is discussing the purpose of the "patience" algorithm in Git.  In it Bram explains how superfluous matching lines can create nasty conflicts that can be tough to resolve but only in the case of fairly complex merges involving large patches.  In other words simple contrived examples will fail to show this behavior.

While he does also mention things like End affecting the results it makes some sense to infer that placing an opening brace on it's own line increases the number of superfluous matching lines possibly resulting in a greater probability of these conflicts.

I'd say this isn't iron-clad, but it does lend some credence to this theory.

> So 'unique lines' is a simple cross-language proxy for 'unimportant
>   lines'.

That quote stands out to me in this discussion, since we are basically matching on what we feel are important lines that are supposed to give us context, however a brace by itself is not important and provides no context.

Answer (score 0):

Pick standard that is easier for you/your team to read over anything else. No matter how your source control system behaves today it will behave better tomorrow, but your code will stay the way you've checked it in for long time.

Comment: The question is more about git - not about which standard is more readable. Here the pref is half and half (some people hate scrolling where as some like the extra white space), so I have an opportunity to use the one that introduces the least friction. The mono project is huge and it uses K&R. Most example code is B&D. I definitely prefer K&R. I don't want to make this about preference. I want to this to ensure the least amount of friction. We do branch-per-feature so there is A LOT of merging. If I can minimize the amount of conflicts, it's a big efficiency win.

Answer (score 0):

We have several large projects (over 200+ code files), which contain a massive mixture of both K&R AND B&D. I can safely say that after almost 2 years on Git, a development staff that is refactoring-crazy, and a rebasing behavior of "several time a day", that I have never had a conflict due to coding standards things. So pick whichever, or both, or neither. It won't matter.

Comment: I'm reluctantly accepting this as the answer. But I will repost when I have the exact steps needed to reproduce the issue.